# How to wrap text in UILabel by character

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

My UILabel should show text wrapped by character, no matter how many words in there.

```
UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 130, 500)];
lbl.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
lbl.text = @"Petter Fergusson";
lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Oxygen-Bold" size:16];
[self.view addSubview:lbl];
```

Roughly I want this:

```
+--------------+
|Petter        |
|Fergusson     |
+--------------+
```

to be like this:

```
+--------------+
|Petter Ferguss|
|on            |
+--------------+
```

How I can achieve this?

Comment: I've been trying to figure this one out and it's baffling me- I can't seem to see a difference in behavior between `NSLineBreakByCharWrapping` and `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping`. Both will break at words if possible and at characters if a single word is too large for the row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` instead of `NSLineBreakByCharWrapping` (scratch that)

UPDATE:

Sorry, I misread original question. Try to replaces spaces in your text with the following Unicode character:

> NO-BREAK SPACE Unicode: U+00A0, UTF-8: C2 A0

This will force UIKit to treat spaces and letters more in a same way and will break lines by character.

Comment: Word wrapping will give the same unwanted result. The asker wants wrapping to happen at the character level regardless of spaces. Both word wrap and char wrap will break at spaces when possible.

Comment: Right. I'm sorry, I misread the original question. See updated version

Comment: This worked for me. So you could just do a `labelText = [labelText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"\u00A0"]` before displaying your label. Still, this shouldn't be necessary, and I feel like this is a bug. I'm submitting this one to Apple.